# How to change the cellspacing whitespace on mouse over event?

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table, highlighting

I use the following attributes for create the Table. I use the `cellSpacing="5"` for space. When I execute the whitespace will appear fine inbetween the cells in  the Table. **How to  change the cellspacing whitespace on mouse over event with another color**? Is This Possible?

```
Table Creation:

    <table border="0" id="TabDeclaration"  width="100%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="3" border="2">
        <tr>
            <td>aaaa</td>
            <td>bbbb</td>
            <td>azaz</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>cccc</td>
            <td>dddd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>eeee</td>
            <td>ffff</td>
        </tr>      
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following to change the `background-color` on hover:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('td').hover(function() {
           $(this).addClass('hover');
        }, function() {
           $(this).removeClass('hover');        
        });
    });
</script>

<style>
    td {
        background-color: red;        
    }

    td.hover {
        background-color: blue;        
    }
</style>
```

[Functional JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/faceleg/4b7Hr/1/).

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: if I use like this background-color the cell spacing's white space still show

Comment: @user attached a screenshot of how my solution appears to me

Comment: in this JSFiddle the td's will select alone.but I try to use tr in style its not working

Comment: I Have two tables in the application.But If I use like this tr {
    background-color: white;        
}

tr.hover {
    background-color: blue;        
}.It will appear the two tables tr.I need this style for one table means how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `cellspacing`. Use `padding`. Then you can just change the background color of the cell.

It might help to give your `td`'s classes so you can target them better with CSS or jQuery selector.

Cellspacing is outside the cell so you can't change the background color. You'd have to change the whole table's background color.

Comment: If I use the style="padding:8" instead of cellspacing =8.The table look is totally changed

Comment: it needs to be `padding:8px` and don't do it as inline styles. Give your `td` a `class` like `<td class="foo">` and in your css you do `td.foo { padding:8px }`